# How many secondary receivers allowed in Paypal chained payment?

Tags: php, paypal

I need to split payment among 8 to 9 receivers. Does Paypal allow this?

Comment: I suspect this question would be best asked directly to Paypal.

Comment: Question should be asked of PayPal support, or looked into PayPal User FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

> Chained Payments
>
> A chained payment is a payment from a sender that is indirectly split
>   among multiple receivers. It is an extension of a typical payment from
>   a sender to a receiver, in which a receiver, known as the primary
>   receiver, passes part of the payment to other receivers, who are
>   called secondary receivers.
>
> Note: The API caller must get permission from PayPal to use chained
>   payments.
>
> **You can have at most one primary receiver and 1-5 secondary receivers.**
>   Chained payments are useful in cases when the primary receiver acts as
>   an agent for other receivers. The sender deals only with the primary
>   receiver and does not know about the secondary receivers, including
>   how a payment is split among receivers. The following example shows a
>   sender making a payment of $100:

Comment: If its working they have an error in their docs or their programmers didn't enforce documented limit. Why are you insulting me for trying to help you? If you know better why are you even asking us? Try it and check. But don't cry if PayPal at some point blocks your account for excessive API usage.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: above argument shows your depth especially "don't cry if PayPal at some point blocks your account for excessive API usage". I thought i would get right answer. Its not about crying its about misguiding users. I too had that reference site, but i wanted to know how many receivers are supported.

Comment: @halfer: Today only i have joined this site, got few idea about how reputation are earned. Down vote if you are confronted with truth that you don't know things.

Comment: Because I don't know how PayPal internals work, neither do you. If the docs state you can have up to 5 receivers, that means in severe case you can be banned if you exceed that. Are you 100% sure you want this? And are you 100% sure this won't happen? What do you mean by "right" answer if docs are everything we have?

Also I live a happy life so your insults won't bother me very much, but you joined StackOverflow today and you already "know better" than any of us? You haven't helped anyone here and you command us from the very beginning? Calm down and think about it.

Comment: Also to be sure - I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: :Sorry, would have chatted with you but not enough reputation. I was too aggressive.

Comment: I have upvoted your question so that it keeps you going towards chat reputation. Good that you rethought your comments - it's not bad if you do bad, it's definitely bad if you don't want to change. You saw your fault and it's good if you want to fix such behavior. :)